# How use preg_replace in PHP to do this example?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a little help. I have a string:

```
$str = "{{abc}} {{cde}}";

$str = preg_replace('/({{\w+}})/', '$1', $str);

echo $str; //{{abc}} {{cde}}
```

But I want each `{{string}}` will return just `string`. For above example will return `abc cde`.

Comment: Note `{` and `}` are special characters in regular expression and should be escaped. You might not get the behavior you expect with other expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the parentheses (capture group) to capture only what you want:

```
$str = preg_replace('/{{(\w+)}}/', '$1', $str);
```

Comment: If i have an array
$array = array(
 'abc' => 'Test 1',
 'cde' => 'Test 2'
);

$str = preg_replace('/{{(\w+)}}/', $array['$1'], $str);

Have any way to do this work. {{abc}} will return $array['abc'] ?

Comment: @chris85 not so fast :). It wasn't stated that way in those answers

Comment: Maybe I need to learn how to use the editor :) I will start with a new question :) Thanks Bro.